# In IOS Two views one view displays details other view is playing music Lock screen controls are not working when we are in first view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In IOS there are two views.Embedded in Navigation Controller First View displays details(TableView) when we click on any element the second view plays music of certain song.When am in sencond view and app moves to background on lock screen play controls are working but when music is playing and I move to first view and then in lock screen play controls are not working.

Code am using is in SecondViewController

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
              [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

in viewDidLoad

```
     AVAudioSession *sharedAVSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

        if ([utils getOSVersion] >= 6.0)
        {
            NSLog(@"AV - going through notification path");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAVASInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
        }

  NSError *err;
          [sharedAVSession setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume error:&err];
```

overriding

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@“REMOTE EVENT!");

    if ( event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (event.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:

                break;



            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:

                [self goToPreviousTrack];

                break;



            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:

                [self goToNextTrack];

                break;



            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:

                NSLog(@"in UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay");

                [self resumeMusic];

                break;



            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:

                NSLog(@"in UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause ");

                [self pauseClicked];

                break;



            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:

                // TODO

                break;



            default:

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey please help am stucked with this isuue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code in viewWillDisappear. Does it turn off listening to remote control events? In that case, that's what will happen when you switch to another view.

You need to make sure that your audio player is around if the view isn't there, that the view doesn't stop listening to remote events when it disappears, and that it reacts properly if remote events arrive.

That may include making sure that the view controller stays alive. Which may mean that you have to make sure it doesn't get released when you switch to another view, and that no new view controller gets created when you switch back to the player view.

Comment: Hi Am not turning off remote control events Even I switch to other view the audio is playing but when lock screen is done from the first view the remote controls are not working but audio is working.How can I make the view controller live?

Comment: Hey am stucked with this isuue please help me out